# How to pass sql entry_ids to playa?

Tags: playa, sql

I trying have a **SQL query** pass some information to a **playa**.
I can fetch the entry ID and even the field output, but can't pass to `exp:playa:`

Here is a cleaned up snippet of the call

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT entry_id AS id FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id IN (100,101,102)"}
    {exp:playa:children var_prefix="widget" entry_id="{id}"}
        {embed="widget/{widget:channel_short_name}" entry_id="{widget:entry_id}"}
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:query}
```

The playa call isn't successfully embedding the templates. I can however grab the playa field directly, but I would have to manually parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on template debugging, you should be able to see if the entry id is being passed correctly to the playa tag.

Answer (score 1):

The Query is good. Setting issue unique to my setup on the database itself. Once DB issue was taken care of, everything worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly close your playa tag pair.

```
{exp:playa:children}
```

Should be

```
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I pasted the snippet wrong, it's closed properly in my test environment though.

Comment: Can you output the playa entry_id to the rendered template?

Comment: Managed to solve it. Dumb settings mistake on DB itself. Thanks for the help though.